# How to identify if a website is secure from selenium java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to automate a scenario where I should verify the connection to the url is secure without any SSL certificate issues.
I am using selenium webdriver with java and the browsers on which I need this are IE and Chrome. I cannot provide any url having this issue due to some security restrictions.
[Issue to be caught](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VymDN.png)

I found an old question ([Check if website has any ssl certificate warnings using Selenium webDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968052/check-if-website-has-any-ssl-certificate-warnings-using-selenium-webdriver)) which was answered only for Firefox and so it is of no use in my case.

Comment: You can use 3rd party service like https://www.wormly.com/test_ssl.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding browser (better say browser profile) settings you can add expectation of specific elements, see attached image for example in IE.

[image: IE SSL issue]

In Chrome those links can not be inspected, let's try something like this:

```
    driver.get(UrlWithSslIssue);
    Thread.sleep(5000); // ofc better wait methods available
    WebElement lnk_advanced_settings = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("ADVANCED"));
    lnk_advanced_settings.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement lnk_continue = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Continue"));

    // lnk_continue.click();
```